# Query to select modified rows from Oracle table (By comparing original table and backup table) from a specific user and specific time perioud

Tags: java, sql, servlets, oracle11g

I have written a query and insert it to Servlet to get modified rows from Oracle table (By comparing original table and backup table) from a specific user and specific time period. The code is working fine and I got the expected result. 
First I get the count of all rows in Backup table and create a loop from that count and insert my select query. the reason is I get the ROWNUM and comparing values. 
But the problem is for a table with huge data set(100000 rows), to get a result it will take around 35 mints.
So can someone give me solution to write my select query without a loop. Is there any solution to get result by executing a single query in oracle.

Original Table : GROUP
Backup Table   : GROUP_BK
By changing "WHERE ROW_NUM = " can get the value
From this table I want to get modified Active Status column

My JAVA SERVLET Code block

```
sql = " " +
  "   SELECT PROFILE_ID,COUNT(*) UPDATECOUNT " +
  "        FROM  " + m_schema_name + ".CO_CO_MAS_USER_PROFILE_BK  " +
  "          GROUP BY PROFILE_ID" +
  " ";

resultSet1 = statement1.executeQuery(sql);
  while (resultSet1.next()) {
    rowVal = Integer.parseInt(resultSet1.getString("UPDATECOUNT"));
    while(rowVal!=0){
    //QUERY
    sql = " " +
    " SELECT BACK_UP_A.PROFILE_ID, BACK_UP_B.PROFILE_DESC, BACK_UP_B.MOD_USER," +
    " NVL(BACK_UP_A.MOD_DATE, BACK_UP_B.MOD_DATE) MOD_DATE, " +
    " CASE WHEN ( BACK_UP_A.ACTIVE_STATUS <> BACK_UP_B.ACTIVE_STATUS ) THEN "+                
    "          BACK_UP_B.ACTIVE_STATUS ELSE '' END PRVS_ACTIVE_STATUS, " +
    " CASE WHEN ( BACK_UP_A.ACTIVE_STATUS <> BACK_UP_B.ACTIVE_STATUS )THEN "+
    "          BACK_UP_A.ACTIVE_STATUS ELSE '' END CURR_ACTIVE_STATUS, " + 
    "   BACK_UP_A.ENT_USER, " +
    "   NVL(BACK_UP_A.MOD_USER, BACK_UP_B.MOD_USER) MOD_USER " +
    "   FROM " +
    "   (SELECT MAIN_TAB.* FROM( " +
    "   SELECT ROWNUM ROW_NUM,A.PROFILE_ID,PROFILE_DESC,COMPANY_CODE, ACTIVE_STATUS, ENT_USER, "+
    "   ENT_DATE, MOD_USER, MOD_DATE " +  "+       
    "   FROM   " + m_schema_name + ".CO_CO_MAS_USER_PROFILE_BK A " +
    "   WHERE ((MOD_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('"+ m_from_date +"','DD-MM-YYYY') "+
    "   AND TO_DATE('"+ m_to_date +"','DD-MM-YYYY')) OR MOD_DATE IS NULL) " +  
    "   AND PROFILE_ID = '"+ resultSet1.getString("PROFILE_ID") +"' " +
    "   UNION " +
    "   SELECT 0 ROW_NUM,A.PROFILE_ID, PROFILE_DESC, COMPANY_CODE, ACTIVE_STATUS, ENT_USER, "+
    "   ENT_DATE, MOD_USER, MOD_DATE " +
    "   FROM   " + m_schema_name + ".CO_CO_MAS_USER_PROFILE A " +
    "   WHERE (MOD_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('"+ m_from_date +"','DD-MM-YYYY') "+
    "   AND TO_DATE('"+ m_to_date +"','DD-MM-YYYY')) " + "+
    "  AND PROFILE_ID = '"+ resultSet1.getString("PROFILE_ID") +"') MAIN_TAB " +
    "  WHERE ROW_NUM = '"+rowVal+"') BACK_UP_A, " +
    "  (SELECT MAIN_TAB.* FROM( " +
    "  SELECT ROWNUM ROW_NUM, A.PROFILE_ID, PROFILE_DESC, COMPANY_CODE, ACTIVE_STATUS, "+
    "  ENT_USER, ENT_DATE, MOD_USER, MOD_DATE  " + 
    "  FROM   " + m_schema_name + ".CO_CO_MAS_USER_PROFILE_BK A " +
    "  WHERE ((MOD_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('"+ m_from_date +"','DD-MM-YYYY') "+
    "   AND TO_DATE('"+ m_to_date +"','DD-MM-YYYY')) OR MOD_DATE IS NULL) " + 
    "  AND PROFILE_ID = '"+ resultSet1.getString("PROFILE_ID") +"' " +
    "  UNION " +
    "  SELECT 0 ROW_NUM,A.PROFILE_ID, PROFILE_DESC, COMPANY_CODE, ACTIVE_STATUS, "+
    "  ENT_USER, ENT_DATE, MOD_USER, MOD_DATE  " +
    "  FROM   " + m_schema_name + ".CO_CO_MAS_USER_PROFILE A " +
    "  WHERE MOD_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('"+ m_from_date +"','DD-MM-YYYY') "+
    "   AND TO_DATE('"+ m_to_date +"','DD-MM-YYYY')) " + "+
    "  AND PROFILE_ID = '"+ resultSet1.getString("PROFILE_ID") +"') MAIN_TAB " +
    "  WHERE ROW_NUM = "+(rowVal-1)+") BACK_UP_B " +
    "  WHERE BACK_UP_A.PROFILE_ID = BACK_UP_B.PROFILE_ID " +
    "  AND BACK_UP_B.MOD_USER LIKE '%"+m_user+"%' " +
    "  ORDER BY BACK_UP_A.MOD_DATE DESC " +
    " ";

    resultSet_4= statement_3.executeQuery(sql);
    while (resultSet_4.next()) {

    //Table to display data
    out.println("<table align=\"center\" width=\"97%\" class=\"table\" border=\"1\" >");
    out.println("               <tr class=\"div_input\" style=\"font-weight: bold;\" >");
    out.println("                   <td colspan='91'><b>User Profile</b></td>");
    out.println("               </tr>");
    out.println("               <tr class=\"div_input\" style=\"font-weight: bold;\">");
    out.println("                   <td width=\"5%\" rowspan=\"2\">PROFILE ID</td>");
    out.println("                   <td width=\"5%\" rowspan=\"2\">PROFILE DESCRIPTION</td>");
    out.println("                   <td width=\"15%\" colspan=\"3\">EDITED FIELDS</td>");
    out.println("                   <td width=\"5%\" rowspan=\"2\">MODIFY USER</td>");
    out.println("                   <td width=\"5%\" rowspan=\"2\">MODIFY DATE</td>");
    out.println("               </tr>");
    out.println("               <tr class=\"div_input\" style=\"font-weight: bold;\">");
    out.println("                   <td width=\"5%\">Field Name</td>");
    out.println("                   <td width=\"5%\">Before</td>");
    out.println("                   <td width=\"5%\">After</td>");
    out.println("               </tr>");

    if(!(resultSet_4.getString("CURR_ACTIVE_STATUS")==null)){
      if(!(resultSet_4.getString("PRVS_ACTIVE_STATUS")==null)){
        out.println("        <tr class=\"div_input\">");
        out.println("          <td>" + resultSet_4.getString("PROFILE_ID") + "</td>");
        out.println("          <td>" + resultSet_4.getString("PROFILE_DESC") + "</td>");
        out.println("          <td>ACTIVE STATUS</td>");
        out.println("          <td>" + resultSet_4.getString("PRVS_ACTIVE_STATUS") + "</td>");
        out.println("          <td>" + resultSet_4.getString("CURR_ACTIVE_STATUS") + "</td>");
        out.println("          <td>" + resultSet_4.getString("MOD_USER") + "</td>");    
        out.println("          <td>" + resultSet_4.getString("MOD_DATE") + "</td>");
        out.println("      </tr>");
             }
            }
        }
       --rowVal;
    }
}
```

out.println("");

So, Please someone give me solution to write my select query without a loop. Is there any solution to get result by executing a single query in oracle.

Many thanks.

Comment: You should provide the (releant part of the) table structure, the criteria for the comparison, and the columns of which table to be returned. Especially helpful: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with structure (and sample data).

Answer (score 0):

Basically you could work along

```
WITH
Original AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 1 a, 1 b FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 2, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 3, 3 FROM DUAL

),
Backup AS (
  SELECT 0 id, 0 a, 0 b FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 2, 2 FROM DUAL
),
SELECT
  O.id
  , O.a a_current
  , B.a a_backup
FROM Original O
 JOIN Backup B
  ON O.id = B.id
  AND O.a != B.a
;
```

General idea:

- Join the tables on the primary key,
- add columns to the join condition, where inequality matters, and
- retrieve the column values, you actually want to report.

This will not catch cases, where:

- no backup record has been created yet (See id 3 in Original.), or
- the original has simply been deleted (See id 0 in Backup.)

(Sorry, SQL Fiddle seems to be broken at the time of this writing.)

Please comment, if any of this needs more detail.

Edit: Your code seems to suggest, you prefer rows over columns (My own preference were probably columns - so I came up with them first. Anyway…):

```
WITH
Original AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 1 a, 1 b FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 2, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 3, 3 FROM DUAL

),
Backup AS (
  SELECT 0 id, 0 a, 0 b FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 2, 2 FROM DUAL
),
Changed AS (
  SELECT
    O.id
  FROM Original O
  JOIN Backup B
    ON O.id = B.id
    AND O.a != B.a
)
SELECT 'Original' flag, O.id, O.a, O.b FROM Original O WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM Changed)
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Backup', B.id, B.a, B.b FROM Backup B WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM Changed)
ORDER BY id, flag
;
```

If there are more column values to be checked for changes, extend the `JOIN` condition for "Changed" like `AND ((O.a != B.a) OR (O.c != B.c) OR (O.x != B.x))`.
Still "no backup record, yet" and "original deleted" not being reported as before.

Appropriate indices will improve performance…

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ea2b0/2/1) is back.

Comment: still not get the expected results. In simple words I need a query to get the Modified rows values (Previous value and updated value). Many thankx for your consideration

Comment: "a_current" and "a_backup" are the respective values. Other columns to be included in the result accordingly. Or do you want the respective records as rows? Feel free to use above example values to specify the expected output.

Comment: Added alternative approach. If you are still looking for something different, please, provide more detail.

Comment: Dear Abecee, I'm new to Oracle. When i run your qquery it producing an error. "Unsupported column aliasing" . " xolumn aliasing in WITH clause is not supported yet. Specify aliasing in dedinition subquery and retry" what I want to do?

Comment: You indicate 11g - which is, what I tested with. Anyway - will adjust…

Comment: Dear Abecee, this link has my requirement and stuff.  https://www.dropbox.com/sh/j72s2o68zszeut5/AAB1ua2up9zXLXtjC8IBlopQa?dl=0.                                                       Thank you very much for your kind concideration.

Answer (score 0):

So - let's start again with the recently supplied details:

```
WITH
Demo AS (
  SELECT 'DEMO_1' id, 'Test' name, 'No 1, Test Road, Test' address, 'Y' active_status, 'SAMI' mod_user, TO_DATE('28/FEB/14', 'DD/MON/YY') mod_date FROM DUAL
),
Demo_BK AS (
  SELECT 'DEMO_1' id, 'Test' name, 'No 1, Test Road, Test' address, 'Y' active_status, NULL mod_user, NULL mod_date FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'DEMO_1', 'Test', 'No 1, Test Road, Test', 'N', 'SAMI', TO_DATE('19/FEB/14', 'DD/MON/YY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'DEMO_1', 'Test', 'No 1, Test Road, Test', 'Y', 'SAMI', TO_DATE('20/FEB/14', 'DD/MON/YY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'DEMO_1', 'Test', 'No 55, Demo Road', 'Y', 'SAMI', TO_DATE('21/FEB/14', 'DD/MON/YY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'DEMO_1', 'Test', 'No 55, Demo Road', 'Y', 'SAMI', TO_DATE('22/FEB/14', 'DD/MON/YY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'DEMO_1', 'Test', 'No 55, Demo Road', 'N', 'SAMI', TO_DATE('23/FEB/14', 'DD/MON/YY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'DEMO_1', 'Test', 'No 55, Demo Road', 'Y', 'SAMI', TO_DATE('24/FEB/14', 'DD/MON/YY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'DEMO_1', 'Test', 'No 55, Demo Road', 'N', 'SAMI', TO_DATE('25/FEB/14', 'DD/MON/YY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'DEMO_1', 'Test', 'No 55, Demo Road', 'Y', 'SAMI', TO_DATE('26/FEB/14', 'DD/MON/YY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'DEMO_1', 'Test', 'No 1, Test Road, Test', 'Y', 'SAMI', TO_DATE('27/FEB/14', 'DD/MON/YY') FROM DUAL
)
SELECT
  CASE WHEN prvs_active_status || curr_active_status != '--' THEN '<tr><td>' || id || '</td><td>' || name|| '</td><td>ACTIVE STATUS</td><td>' || prvs_active_status || '</td><td>' || curr_active_status || '</td><td>' || mod_user || '</td><td>' || TO_CHAR(mod_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') || '</td></tr>'
       WHEN prvs_address || curr_address != '--' THEN '<tr><td>' || id || '</td><td>' || name || '</td><td>ADDRESS</td><td>' || prvs_address || '</td><td>' || curr_address || '</td><td>' || mod_user || '</td><td>' || TO_CHAR(mod_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') || '</td></tr>' END line
FROM
  (SELECT Back_Up_A.row_num, Back_Up_A.id, Back_Up_A.name, Back_Up_B.mod_user, Back_Up_B.MOD_DATE,
  CASE WHEN (Back_Up_A.active_status <> Back_Up_B.active_status ) THEN Back_Up_B.active_status ELSE '-' END prvs_active_status,
  CASE WHEN (Back_Up_A.active_status <> Back_Up_B.active_status ) THEN Back_Up_A.active_status ELSE '-' END curr_active_status,
  CASE WHEN (Back_Up_A.address <> Back_Up_B.address ) THEN Back_Up_B.address ELSE '-' END prvs_address,
  CASE WHEN (Back_Up_A.address <> Back_Up_B.address ) THEN Back_Up_A.address ELSE '-' END curr_address
  FROM
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY mod_date DESC NULLS LAST) row_num, id, name, address, active_status, mod_user, mod_date
    FROM DEMO_BK
    WHERE (MOD_DATE <= TO_DATE('01-NOV-2014', 'DD-MON-YYYY') OR mod_date IS NULL)
      AND id = 'DEMO_1'
    ) Back_Up_A
  JOIN    
    (SELECT * FROM
      (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY mod_date DESC) ROW_NUM, id, name, address, active_status, mod_user, mod_date
      FROM DEMO_BK
      WHERE (MOD_DATE <= TO_DATE('01-NOV-2014', 'DD-MON-YYYY'))
        AND id = 'DEMO_1')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 0 ROW_NUM,A.ID, NAME, address, active_status, MOD_USER, MOD_DATE
    FROM DEMO A
    WHERE MOD_DATE <= TO_DATE('01-NOV-2014', 'DD-MON-YYYY')
    AND id = 'DEMO_1') Back_Up_B
    ON Back_Up_A.row_num = Back_Up_B.row_num + 1
  WHERE Back_Up_B.mod_date != TO_DATE('19-FEB-2014', 'DD-MON-YYYY'))
WHERE (prvs_active_status || curr_active_status || prvs_address || curr_address) != '----' 
ORDER BY row_num
;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8db48/1/0)

Comment: This query working fine. I got the expected result Abecee. This one is more more efficiency. Many thankx abecee. . .

Comment: Glad, it worked out. Feel free to accept this as the answer to your question.